# HalfSpace to Point Test

Tags: c++, math, geometry, box2d, physics

I'd like to know more about a very specific way of getting the distance of a point to a line in 2D. Here's how it's done:

```
// Given an arbitrary point, and a normal vector
// to a line along with a scalar offset
distance = DotProduct(normal, point) - offset
```

I know this to be true because Erin Catto is using this method in his Box2D Lite source code. On [this page](http://www.miguelcasillas.com/?p=43) a programmer mentions the equation:

```
distance = (V dot normal) - offset
```

This the only resource I can find for such a computation. The *usual* way of checking for halfspace intersection with a point is to dot a vector from the plane in question to your point, and then see if it is facing away from or towards the normal to that plane by checking the sign (+ or -) of the resulting scalar.

This can be undesirable in real-time applications where finding a point on the plane (or 2D line in this case) can be expensive, and you only have the normal to this line along with the offset.

So in short, what is this "offset" and how can you compute it? What is this offset representing? From what I currently know of my own research my best guess is that it's the c variable from the general equation of a line in 2D:

```
ax + by + c = 0
```

**Additional info**:
Erin Catto is computing his offset like this in a few places (in the context of Oriented Bounding Box collision detection), but I don't understand the math here or what's going on:

```
offsetScalar = Dot(BoxPositionVector, normalVector) + BoxYHalfWidthScalar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A halfspace in `n` dimensions is defined uniquely by the equation

```
a * x >= c
```

Where `a` and `x` are vectors of length `n`, `*` is the scalar (dot) product, and `c` is a scalar. `a` is a vector that is orthogonal to the hyperplane `a * x = c`. As you said, in two dimensions this is the equation `ax + by - c = 0`, all scalars.

What you said is exactly right; the `offset` is related to the value of this constant `c`. For any point `p` in the hyperplane, you will have `a * p = c`. For any point in the halfspace, you will have `a * p >= c`. Any point not in the halfspace will satisfy `a * p < c`.

For some point `p`, the value of `a * p - c` will also give you the orthogonal distance from the point to the hyperplane - if `a` is a unit vector. This is because of the [equivalence of definition of dot product to scalar projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Scalar_projection_and_the_equivalence_of_the_definitions); `a/||a|| * p` is the projection of `p` onto `a`. Hence when defining hyperplanes in computation it is convenient to normalize `a` and scale `c` accordingly. The `c` is then the offset, or equivalently the distance from the hyperplane to the origin - we must adjust for this after projecting on to `a`.

**TL;DR version**: `offset = c/||a||`, which means `offset = c` if `a` is a unit vector.

Answer (score 1):

The `offset` is the distance from the line to the origin, if the line is represented as :

```
 ax + by + c = 0
```

Then `offset = c/sqrt(a*a+b*b).`

See [here](http://www.ditutor.com/line/point-line.html) for more info.

Comment: Helpful to know. I didn't realize that C related to the origin in this way.